# How to display/render XHTML source code directly after pasting?

Tags: selenium, jsf, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone, graphene2

In my current use of Arquillian, it makes a  lot of sense to debug functional tests with Graphene (wrapping Selenium) with `WebDriver.getPageSource` in the debugger which allows to easily copy the XHTML code into the clipboard. However, I need to create a temporary document in an editor, save the file and open it in a browser.

Is there any browser or website which allows to paste XHTML source code and render it (directly or in an IFrame)?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WYSIWYG editors are available for free on websites, e.g. https://html-online.com. Of course, the CSS isn't included, but it won't if the file was saved like described in the question.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to your question or additional info? This should probably be part of the question... especially since you posted it at the same time as your question.

Comment: @JeffC I didn't find info for this task and started the question, then I remembered the term WYSIWYG and searched that with success and then I didn't want to throw away the question since it might ease the way to find this info and used the "answer your own question" function. I see that it's not ideal, but also not a completely nonsense and terrible question. I give it up to the review process...